# Need help extracting data from .dat file

Tags: file-format

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/247623/item.dat
This is a file from a Java game, and I would like to know how to legible string data from it.

I would prefer if only hints were given to me.

I have looked into it with a Hex Editor and come to the conclusion that the file is either compressed or encrypted because of the lack of a pattern.

If it is encrypted, I have no idea how to proceed.
If it is compressed, I have found the following but have no idea how to proceed.

> Entropy = 7.999055 bits per byte.
>
> Optimum compression would reduce the size of this 384802 byte file by
>   0 percent.
>
> Chi square distribution for 384802 samples is 505.10, and randomly
>   would exceed this value less than 0.01 percent of the times.
>
> Arithmetic mean value of data bytes is 128.1314 (127.5 = random).
>   Monte Carlo value for Pi is 3.120328068 (error 0.68 percent). Serial
>   correlation coefficient is -0.031097 (totally uncorrelated = 0.0).

Assume I have minimal knowledge of what I am doing, so several hints may be required.
More information can be given upon request.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Reverse the program that used the file, as it is java this is probably the easiest solutions. Just JD-GUI or something similar.

Answer (score 7):

Piece of cake: this is ZIP-compatible compressed compiled Java. Any familiar sequences of bytes near the header?

```
FA CE AF 0E 10 00 10 00 78 9C AC DD ..
```

.. those first few bytes *look* like Java's magic ID `CA FE BA BE`, but Googling that sequence doesn't yield any results, and it might be a red herring anyway. Next up: `10 00 10 00`, which can be about anything (not a file length, but perhaps some internal flag or ID).

Next: `78 9C`. These *are* familiar, they may form a set of ZLIB compatible compression flags. A quick-and-dirty ZLIB unpacker gave me (1) a *positive* unpacking result (meaning this data *is* valid compressed data and could be uncompressed), and (2) an output file much larger than the input (1,388,603 bytes vs. the original 384,802).

Inspecting the decompressed data I found this at the start:

```
01 09 00 31 5B 4C 63 6F 6D 2E 74 68 72 65 65 72 69 6E 67
73 2E 70 72 6F 6A 65 63 74 78 2E 69 74 65 6D 2E 63 6F 6E
```

or, in ASCII,

```
...1[Lcom.threering
s.projectx.item.con
```

-- enough to conclude it has been decompressed successfully. From this point on, you should be able to use common Java-decrypting/decompiling techniques.

Answer (score 3):

It can be difficult to differentiate well compressed data (e.g., LZMA) from well encrypted data (e.g., AES). I've done a [bit](http://www.devttys0.com/2013/06/differentiate-encryption-from-compression-using-math/) of [analysis](http://www.devttys0.com/2013/06/encryption-vs-compression-part-2/) in the past however, and found that a lot of compressed data can be distinguished from encrypted data based on entropy analysis, as you have obviously already done.

However, I would take a simpler approach first. Look for common "magic" strings and/or headers in the file, such as those for gzip, zlib, and lzma. It may be that the game developers are using a standard compression, they've just added a custom header for their application.

Comment: Yep, a set of common ZLIB compression flags can be found near the start.