# Where could one find a collection of mid-file binary signatures?

Tags: file-format, magic-number

While reading [an answer to another question](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/2996/115), it was mentioned that "`78 9C`" was a well-known pattern for Zlib compressed data. Intrigued, I decided to search up the signature on [the file signature database](http://www.filesignatures.net/index.php?search=789c&mode=SIG) to see if there were any related numbers. It wasn't on there. So I checked on [Gary Kessler's magic number list](http://www.garykessler.net/library/file_sigs.html) to see that it wasn't there either.

I even ended up creating a binary file with the signature at the beginning and ran "`file`" on it as a sort of *"I-doubt-it-will-work-but-maybe"* attempt (Since that works with "`50 4b`" because that is a valid ZIP file header and is commonly in the middle of other files.) But none of these attempts revealed that I was looking at a Zlib signature.

It would appear as though most magic number databases only contain file-format magic numbers rather than numbers to differentiate data in the middle of a file. So, my question is:

Are there any places one could find a list of binary signatures of certain types of data streams that are *not* file formats themselves? Data that is not a file itself, but rather *inside* a file.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Only FYI: the sequence `78 9C` in itself is not magic -- if it was, it would be a fixed signature. The first two bytes of a ZLib compressed file contain flags whose settings are needed for a correct decompression; and certain configurations are more common than others. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9050260/what-does-a-zlib-header-look-like for 3 of the most common, and [RFC1950](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1950) for their meaning. I'd have to re-read the RFC but I *think* these 2 bytes can have just about *any* value, and still be a valid ZLib header.

Comment: (Add.) Consider a 'directory' kind of file, where each first long word indicate the length of the next raw chunk. Easy to spot for a human, but hard for a computer (unless specifically told to).

Comment: Aye... I've taken a look at the specification and there appears to be very few invalid values for the following bytes. And indeed, I don't really mean to refer to the values as magic numbers since those reference file formats, which is the reason I called them "binary signatures". (Though I am not %100 sure that is correct either.) Some signatures *can* be magic numbers though, which was why I used magic number databases for my initial checking.

Also that directory-style file is actually a really good example. Kudos..!

Comment: Full set of possible zlib stream headers: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.compression/_y2Wwn_Vq_E/EymIVcQ52cEJ

Comment: Thanks, Igor, for that link -- always nice to see an answer from a Definitive Authority. Note his comment "..You would follow this with an attempted decompression.." , in other words: "the proof is in the pudding". If one finds any of these magic pairs, how many bytes would one need to decode to be more than a bit sure? (That is, apart from "all of them". ;-)

Comment: That's all kinds of nifty. Will need to read up on it s bit. (And also subscribe to a new news group by the looks of things.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you perhaps looking for [binwalk](https://code.google.com/p/binwalk/)? Especially the *magic* folder of its source code.

Comment: Neat. A quick grep reveals that the header was Zlib in [this](http://binwalk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/magic/compressed) file. The tool itself looks pretty cool, too. Thanks.

Comment: The code is moved to https://github.com/ReFirmLabs/binwalk
Please update your link